# Programmatically Take Picture Without User Interaction

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

How do I take Picture without User Interaction or without presenting ImagePickerController

```
  UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    }

    // image picker needs a delegate,
    [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];

    // Place image picker on the screen
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    _myImageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

I know this way I can take picture but automatically How I do accomplish?

Comment: Are you planning to put this app in App store? Then dont...

Comment: @Anil Is there some violation of AppStore Rules?

Comment: Don't use `UIImagePickerController` but write you own camera capture with [`AVFoundation`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2).

Comment: @Anil why not? What if I want to make a Selfie that counts down and takes a picture. Or a timelapse app?

Comment: There also user initiating the action and he is aware about it. Can take photo without using `UIImagePickerController` but without the user interaction is a violation i feel

Comment: @rckoenes using Above code it present view controller than user tap on capture then we get image. but i want to tap capture button programatically. Is there any way???

Comment: AVFoundation image capture - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html

Comment: @Ty_ I linked to that one in my comment ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`takePicture`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-SW24) method on [`UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) to take a picture programmaticly.

But I suggest to use [`AVFoundation`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2) to create you onw image capture.

Comment: is there any good tutorial which i should have to follow , I google it  but i didn't find as according to my scenario .