# How to capture image from camera without user interaction using Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios-camera

I want to capture series of images based on the device orientation (using compass) but my specific requirement is to capture automatically without the need to manually taking photos which is the only way i could find possible.
Im using Xamarin.Mobile library and also tried Medai Plugin from Xamarin components .

```
if (CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable && CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {

        var mediaOptions = new Media.Plugin.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions()
        {
        Directory = "Receipts",
        Name = "test.jpg"

        };


        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(mediaOptions);
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programatically Take Picture Without User Interaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548433/programatically-take-picture-without-user-interaction)

Comment: Thanks ,although the code is not in mono ,but i guess it helps